# Big Range of separated cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(target, Range("??")) Is Nothing Then GoTo Einde
If IsEmpty(target) Then GoTo Einde

If Hour(target.Value) <> 0 Or Minute(target.Value) <> 0 Then GoTo Einde
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Int(target.Value / 100) < 0.1 Then
target = "00:" & target.Value
Else
target = Int(target.Value / 100) & ":" & Right(target.Value, 2)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

The two question marks in the third line of code need to be the following range:

```
Dim aRng, bRng, cRng, dRng, uRng As Range
Set aRng = Range("B5,B7,B9,B11,B13,B15,B17,B19,B21,B26,B28,B30,B32,B34,B36,B38,B40,B42,B47,B49,B51,B53,B55,B57,B59,B61,B63,B68,B70,B72,B74,B76,B78,B80,B82,B84,B89,B91,B93,B95,B97,B99,B101,B103,B105,B110,B112,B114,B116,B118,B120,B122,B124,B126,B131,B133,B135,B137,B139,B141,B143,B145,B147")
Set bRng = Range("F5,F7,F9,F11,F13,F15,F17,F19,F21,F26,F28,F30,F32,F34,F36,F38,F40,F42,F47,F49,F51,F53,F55,F57,F59,F61,F63,F68,F70,F72,F74,F76,F78,F80,F82,F84,F89,F91,F93,F95,F97,F99,F101,F103,F105,F110,F112,F114,F116,F118,F120,F122,F124,F126,F131,F133,F135,F137,F139,F141,F143,F145,F147")
Set cRng = Range("J5,J7,J9,J11,J13,J15,J17,J19,J21,J26,J28,J30,J32,J34,J36,J38,J40,J42,J47,J49,J51,J53,J55,J57,J59,J61,J63,J68,J70,J72,J74,J76,J78,J80,J82,J84,J89,J91,J93,J95,J97,J99,J101,J103,J105,J110,J112,J114,J116,J118,J120,J122,J124,J126,J131,J133,J135,J137,J139,J141,J143,J145,J147")
Set dRng = Range("N5,N7,N9,N11,N13,N15,N17,N19,N21,N26,N28,N30,N32,N34,N36,N38,N40,N42,N47,N49,N51,N53,N55,N57,N59,N61,N63,N68,N70,N72,N74,N76,N78,N80,N82,N84,N89,N91,N93,N95,N97,N99,N101,N103,N105,N110,N112,N114,N116,N118,N120,N122,N124,N126,N131,N133,N135,N137,N139,N141,N143,N145,N147")
Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng, dRng)'
```

But I can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas where the problem is?

Thanks for you input.

Comment: Can you describe the error or what is not working correctly

Comment: You don't get it to work. Why not? What do you see, which is different from what you expect? What do you expect? Do you have an error message?

Comment: For starters Int(target.Value / 100)  will never be less than 0.1 unless it's zero - as it's an integer

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to select the cells, but your code to actually alter the value needs playing with

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If IsEmpty(target) Then
   'do nothing
Else

    Select Case target.Column
        Case 2, 5, 9, 14
            Select Case target.Row
                 Case 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 131, 133, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145, 147

                    'these are the cells you want

            End Select
        Case Else
          'do nothing
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: F is the 6th column not the 5th; J is the 10th column not the 9th.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

'invoeren van tijd in gehele getallen

If IsEmpty(target) Then
   'do nothing
Else
Select Case target.Column
    Case 2, 6, 10, 14
        Select Case target.Row
             Case 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 131, 133, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145, 147
                'these are the cells you want
        End Select

        On Error Resume Next
        If Hour(target.Value) <> 0 Or Minute(target.Value) <> 0 Then GoTo Einde
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Int(target.Value / 100) < 0.1 Then
        target = "00:" & target.Value
        Else
        target = Int(target.Value / 100) & ":" & Right(target.Value, 2)
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    Case Else
      'do nothing
End Select
End If
Einde:
ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```